Pointer gives garbage values if using virtual inheritance
I have a storage class that stores void pointers (I know that is questionable design but I didn't design it) to arbitrary types of data.
While writing a unit test, I noticed that I get a segfault when the data is returned from the storage.
Using the MS visual debugger, I noticed the values in the returned pointer are all invalid. Anyone knows why? It only happens if B virtually inherits from A. Is there a way to make the retrieval work?
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeindex>
#include <memory>

    struct MapKey final
    {
        std::string name;
        std::type_index type;
    };

    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const MapKey& lhs, const MapKey& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.type < rhs.type)
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::less;
        }

        if (lhs.type > rhs.type)
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::greater;
        }

        return lhs.name <=> rhs.name;
    };

    bool operator==(const MapKey& lhs, const MapKey& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs <=> rhs) == std::strong_ordering::equal;
    }
    
    template <typename D>
    MapKey makeKey(D* data = nullptr)
    {
        auto const& type = (data == nullptr) ? typeid(D) : typeid(*data);
        std::string typen{type.name()};
        return MapKey{typen, type};
    }

    struct Hasher final
    {
        auto operator()(const MapKey& key) const -> size_t
        {
            return std::hash<std::type_index>{}(key.type) ^ std::hash<std::string>{}(key.name);
        }
    };

    class DataMap
    {
    public:
        template <typename D>
        void setData(std::shared_ptr<D> spData)
        {
            m_dataMap[makeKey<D>(spData.get())] = spData;
        } 

        template <typename D>
        [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<D> getData() const
        {
            auto const data = m_dataMap.find(makeKey<D>());
            if (data != m_dataMap.end())
            {
                return std::static_pointer_cast<D>(data->second);
            }
            return nullptr;
        }

    private:
        using DATA_MAP = std::unordered_map<MapKey, std::shared_ptr<void>, Hasher>;
        DATA_MAP m_dataMap;
    };
    
class A
{
public:
    virtual size_t size() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    size_t size() const override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};
    
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> spA = std::make_shared<B>(); // base ptr (requirement)

    auto k1 = makeKey<A>(spA.get());
    auto k2 = makeKey<B>();

    auto h1 = Hasher()(k1);
    auto h2 = Hasher()(k2);

    auto const& tAB = typeid(*spA);
    auto const& tB = typeid(B);
    if (tAB != tB) {
        std::cout << "Different types for tAB & tB!"<< std::endl;
    }

    if (h1 != h2) {
        std::cout << "Different hashes!"<< std::endl;
    }

    DataMap ds;
    ds.setData(spA);
    auto spGet = ds.getData<B>();

    auto const& tGet = typeid(*spGet);  // Segfault
    if (tGet != tB) {
        std::cout << "Different types for tGet & tB!"<< std::endl;
    }

    if (spGet.get() != spA.get()) {
        std::cout << "Different pointers!"<< std::endl;
    }

    if (spGet->size() != 2) {
        std::cout << "Different sizes!"<< std::endl;
    }
}

Tried not to use virtual inheritance for B. Pointer returned correctly.

Virtual (and multiple) inheritance causes the base to be at a non-zero offset in the derived class.

Also the comparisons for MapKey are designed weirdly. You could just default <=>. If you insist on writing == and <=> manually, == shouldn't be implemented in terms of <=>, because that's slower (== on strings can compare the sizes first, and return early if they're different; <=> can't). And <=> should call <=> on .type, not < and > separately.

you could use std::any to avoid segfaults, the extraction will fail with an exception

When casting to void* and back again the resulting pointer type has to be the same as the original pointer type to avoid this problem

@HolyBlackCat can you elaborate further on how this offset causes the problem?

I mean, isn't it obvious? If you pass a pointer to base, then ask a pointer for the derived (or vice versa), not applying the offset will break things.

@HolyBlackCat ok that makes sense. But why can't the compiler produce some instructions to apply that offset when we do the static_pointer_cast?

static_pointer_cast can only do that when both pointers are not void *. If at least one of them are, it acts as a reinterpret_cast.

@DDDDDDDD -- the correct offset depends on the original type of the pointer; consider a derived class with two bases; the two bases have different addresses, and a void* doesn't carry any information about which base it points at. Moral: don't throw away type information; you can't get it back if you need it later.
